# Android Studio Emulator Not Running

Tags: java, android, android-studio, emulation

[image: some of the pics are here and name of emulator is appearing fadeenter image description here]I am not able to run emulator neither on my phone nor on laptop

Name of emulator is appearing fade and what I have done I don't know
and also in log cat it is showing disconnected.
I have deleted the previous emulator (same problem) and downloaded new one but still have same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just next to the emulator drop down showing `Pixel 5...`, you will see `TimeTableManager` (as I can see in the given img) with a drop down menu. Select `app` from that dropdown menu and try running. This shall resolve your problem with USB debug as well as emulator...